# What is a good place to start with embedding Dart 2 into your own application?

Tags: dart

What are the differences between them and which should I use to embed Dart into my application?

- `libdart_jit`
- `libdart_nosnapshot_with_precompiler`
- `libdart_precompiled_runtime`
- `libdart_with_precompiler`

Would be grateful if someone would able to explain Dart VM lifetime in application in terms of minimum necessary steps to *Initialize*, *Run*, *Cleanup*.